# Why can't I switch between workbooks in Excel 2010 using ALT-TAB?

Tags: microsoft-excel, hotkeys

When using Windows 7 and Excel 2010, I found that I was suddenly no longer able to switch between workbooks using the keyboard accelerator ALT-TAB, although I could use ALT-TAB to switch between multiple windows opened in the same workbook. Any suggestions?

Comment: They have changed the Excel short key from <kbd>ALT + Tab</kbd> to <kbd>CTRL + TAB</kbd>

Comment: I have program suggestion :) http://www.office-tabs.com/download.htm

Answer (score 8):

I found the answer on another [site](http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/385608-can-t-swap-between-excel),

- In Excel Options -> Advanced -> Display -> Uncheck "Show all windows in the Taskbar",
- Click "OK" to close the menu.
- Then go back and select it again (check the option) and click "OK".

Now all windows are available for Alt+Tab again

Comment: You should re-start excel too.. (at least it was in my case)

Answer (score 4):

On more modern versions of Excel, you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>  rather than <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch between workbooks.

Comment: This was pointed out 23 Sept 2015 ...

Comment: Not as an answer though.

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for a solution to get back the old Alt-Tab functionality when working with Microsoft Excel under Windows 10. By default, if you wish to switch between two separate Excel files with Alt-Tab you need to press Alt and then twice Tab. This new feature was a pain for me.

The first solution is to use the Registry workaround as mentioned here: http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-get-the-old-alt-tab-dialog-in-windows-10/. That does the job.

However, I found a more elagant solution if you would like to keep the new look of Alt-Tab (i.e. visual previews of the open programs). Create the following easy [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script:

```
[SetTitleMatchMode, 2
#IfWinActive, Microsoft Excel
{
    LAlt & Tab::
    Send, {Alt Down}{Tab}{Tab}{Alt Up}
    Return
}
#IfWinActive][1]
```

Put it in the Windows autostart and it works like a charm!!

Comment: Alt-twice tab is just alt-tab twice...

Answer (score 1):

Just want to update this question with the following specifications.

- OS: Windows 10 Enterprise
- Office: Office Home and Business 2010

Backup your registry before making any changes.

In the computer registry (`regedit.exe`), go to:

```
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Excel.Sheet.12\shell\Open\Command
```

Change the last values to include both `/e` and `"%1"`. See below for example:

```
(Default) REG_SZ "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.EXE" /e "%1"
command REG_MULTI_SZ "xb'BV5!!!!4!!!!MKKSkEXCELFiles>u2BeT,8X[=]9==,*)Nn] /e "%1"
```

Then rename `ddexec` to `ddexec2`, so it will not use the old folder. It will be like what is shown below:

```
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Excel.Sheet.12\shell\Open\ddexec2
```

Then should be done on `Excel.Sheet.8` too, exactly the same as above:

```
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Excel.Sheet.8\shell\Open\Command --> replace the last part with /e "%1"
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Excel.Sheet.8\shell\Open\ddeexec --> rename to ddeexec2
```

Then try to open two Excel files and use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to toggle between the two applications.

[image: Windows 10 Regedit]

Comment: Are you OP? Is this an update the question or an attempt at an answer. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this same issue, but have a work around:

View Ribbon --> Arrange All (alt, W, A)

Click the option that says "Windows of active workbook"

It doesn't seem to matter if you tile, cascade, etc when you have this box checked. Now Ctrl+tab works for me to toggle between my excel workbooks within the same instance. Alt+Tab still works for all windows, including each individual workbook.

Hope this helps!
Love,
Chicago Joe