# Alt+Tab on Excel 2010 re-selects the current Excel window by default

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel-2010, alt-tab

I have a problem with Microsoft Office 2010 on Windows 10.

The Microsoft Office suite of programs behaves inconsistently with regards to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. By default Excel, Word, Powerpoint, Publisher, and Visio all display multiple windows in the taskbar. Word, Powerpoint, and Publisher allow <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>ing between documents as if each window was a separately opened program. Visio only has a single item in the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> list, no matter how many windows (documents) are open, so documents can't be switched between with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Worst of all, Excel treats each window as a separate item as most of the Office programs do, but if an Excel document (spreadsheet) is the active program, the highlight is "sticky", staying on the first item in the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> list (Excel) instead of moving to the second item as all other programs do. It is necessary to keep holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> while letting go of <kbd>Tab</kbd> and then pressing it a second time to get the second item to highlight. After this, further <kbd>Tab</kbd> presses work as normal. I.e. pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> once and letting go of both keys has no useful effect if Excel is the active program, as the same document remains as the active one.

**This seems to only happen if there are two spreadsheets open at the same time. When only one spreadsheet is open, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> behaves as expected if Excel is initially focused.**

This answer: https://superuser.com/a/923381/148107 says to uncheck `File` => `Options` => `Advanced` => `Display` => `Show all windows in the Taskbar`. While this does allow <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to work the same for Excel as it does for other programs, Excel no longer works the way the rest of the Office suite does because <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> can't be used to switch between documents anymore, as well as hiding all non-active documents on the taskbar (different from Visio, where all the documents are available on the taskbar, but only the active one appears in the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> task list).

Is there a way to get the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> list (with window preview) to automatically highlight the second item on a single press if Excel is the currently active program, and Excel document switching is enabled?